# Deploying Django on Apache: Internal server error

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I can run Django locally just fine, but I can't deploy it using Apache.

My error logs:

```
    [time 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23027:tid 140623621068672] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [time 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 23278:tid 139675061790592] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
    [time 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 23278:tid 139675061790592] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
    [time 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23278:tid 139675061790592] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName xxx.yyy.zzz

            #https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04
            Alias /static /home/user/project/app/static

            <Directory /home/user/project/app/static>
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <Directory /home/user/project/project>
                    <Files wsgi.py>
                            Require all granted
                    </Files>
            </Directory>

            WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/user/project python-home=/home/user/project/env

            WSGIProcessGroup project
            WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/project/wsgi.py
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

I don't have any http.conf file or log.

Comment: Your "errors" are not errors. What actual errors do you have, and what do you see?

Comment: My error is that when I access my website I see an Internal Server Error message instead of my website

Comment: Well at that point there will be errors in the log; please show them.

Comment: I have already posted the errors that I found in /var/log/apache2/errors.log   --- are there any other error logs too?

Comment: Does the ``access.log`` even say it received your request? Are you sure you don't have another web server actually listening on port 80, such as nginx?